Photoshop - Create multiple artboards from layers
I'm trying to make a psd file where each artboard shows a different scene in the animation film I'm working on. For our production pipeline, each scene is often in a separate .ai file, and I want to group them easily in an "overview" psd file.
I usually import (link) each file into an artboard on the psd, create new artboard, import, repeat... It works, but is very tedious for larger projects. Ideally, I'd like an option/script to import all files at once and put them each in their separate artboard.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you for your advice :)

Could you use Photoshop Contact Sheet II plugin? This arranges images into a grid. Or Data Merge in InDesign?

Thx for the tip! One of the advantages of PS artboards is to be able to treat each image separately (easier to export all artboards in a pdf, or to do further editing) : does Contact Sheet just make an image grid or can it arrange artboards?

It would just make an image grid. So you need both an overview showing all of the scenes and another file showing the individual scenes as a PDF page?

It would just be one file really: I currently use a 'master' .psd file where I import all the separate .ai scenes as linked files. I then use this master file to access the linked scenes easily, and to export the whole thing as pdf to show clients. PS artboards work for this, it's just the dispatching of linked files into artboards that I'd like to automate if possible.
